# Thumbnail different from actual image

Tags: magento

Here is a scenerio, on my products page I want to add an image of the product dimensions but for this image I want to use thumbnail which is different from the actual image which will say Dimensions. This will be applied to all the products across the store. So there will be one thumnail image for all the products that will be associated with it’s dimensional image. I want to show it on the gallery page as last image.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Avian

Comment: If all products will have a dimensions image, the simplest solution will be to use JavaScript to replace the 'src' attribute of the last thumbnail on the product page to that of the dimensions image.

Comment: I ain't v good in javascript unfortunately. could you please tell how can this be implemented. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want every product to have a thumbnail that can be set to be one of several images.

You will need to create a custom attribute for your products, and then programmatically set your current inventory to your defaults. (Or manually change them) There is a [knowledgebase article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) that will assist you with custom options (if applicable), or [another article](http://blogs.ifuelinteractive.com/2009/09/29/create-a-new-product-attribute-and-then-using-it-on-a-page-in-magento/) I found via Google to assist in custom attributes.

Comment: Hi Zschuessler, Cags' answer is closer to my question as i want the last gallery image's thumbnail to be different(custom) that would say something like DIMENSIONS and when clicked will show the dimension image in the same gallery same way other images are shown!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not the best way of doing it, but an example of the JavaScript method I was talking about is simply to add the following into a JS file on your server.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.catalog-product-view .image-thumb:last img').each(function(item){item.src = 'http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cags, I'm trying to work along these lines. Fingers crossed